# oddness with http to https through .htaccess

Tags: http, https

So I put these commands in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and something peculiar happened. In my HostGator access logs, I never saw reportage of download success (as in Apache code 200). I seemed to get mainly 301 redirect notifications. That is, people were downloading stuff fine, but I never saw any indication of that in my access logs. Can someone explain to me why that is? I am an Apache novice, so pardon my misunderstanding.

I removed those lines and, yep, all my expected code 200 notifications returned.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK,I think it's pretty clear. But if people don't know what .htaccess is, or what Apache error codes are, I guess I'm in the wrong place. The question I was asking was WHY the code I listed caused my access log to not include download successes.